# Is there anyway to recover from being knocked down?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

Certain attacks will knock me down and I won't be able to get up for awhile. Some of the colossus will knock you down with everyone one of your attacks, and due to their attack patterns can result in being hit once being a game over, since the moment you get back up they attack. This is beyond annoying, and I'm curious if there is some way to get up that I'm missing.

Is there anyway to get up after such an attack?

Comment: Must. Resist. Urge. To edit. Title. To: "I got knocked down. Can I get up again?"

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - These youngsters probably don't even get the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, tapping the jump button (triangle by default) should help you to get up faster.

Answer (score 0):

Twirl that left analog stick after you get knocked down, you'll recover twice as fast.